# Wear OS, Watch cannot not download zvoice package for tts

Tags: android, text-to-speech, wear-os

So, we do have a TicWatch Pro 1182, Model WF12069, Wear OS 2.17, system version H. On that watch I do have an App in use that makes huge use the google TTS feature. That worked pretty until a couple of weeks ago, when we had to reset the watch so it could be coupled to another phone.

And now, it seems to be unable to download that zvoice package necessary for offline tts any more. As long as the watch does have direct access to the internet it can at least speak out the example from the input help menu, using a non local speech package. But as soon as there is no internet available any more, if fails to do so.

The app log did not hint whats wrong (tts yields an "onError", but it uses the deprecated API where no error code is supplied), but I noticed that I can watch the system log unfold when the watch is attached using the usb-charger and android studio is open using logcat.

Next step was to deactivate the "speech app" (sorry for unclear wording, but my system in in German and I don't have the original English names at hand), delete its files (which also clears its cache), restart the watch, then reactivating it, and opening the input help menu for the tts (speech synthesis, as its called) and observing the logcat... which tells me this

```
2020-09-08 08:23:59.712 9249-9249/? I/TTS: Loading library tts_android_neon
2020-09-08 08:24:00.935 9249-9249/? I/TTS: Cache cleared
2020-09-08 08:24:00.959 9249-9249/? I/TTS: Creating Google TTS service, version 3.15.18.200023596
2020-09-08 08:24:01.278 8190-8229/? D/DownloadManager: Scheduling download DownloadInfo:
      mId=13 mLastMod=1599546241141 mPackage=com.google.android.tts mUid=10032 
      mUri=https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/tts/v16/de-de-r2.zvoice 
      mMimeType=null mCookies=no mReferer=no mUserAgent=null 
      mFileName=null mDestination=4 
      mStatus=PENDING mCurrentBytes=0 mTotalBytes=-1 
      mNumFailed=0 mRetryAfter=0 mETag=null mIsPublicApi=true 
      mAllowedNetworkTypes=-1 mAllowRoaming=true mAllowMetered=false mFlags=0 
2020-09-08 08:24:01.303 9249-9249/? I/TTS: Voice download for de-de-x-nfh-lstm-embedded dispatched
2020-09-08 08:24:01.321 750-750/? I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
2020-09-08 08:24:01.418 9249-9262/? I/TTS: For default lang de-de is name de-DE-language (de-de-x-nfh-server)
2020-09-08 08:24:01.429 750-1724/? I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
2020-09-08 08:24:01.430 750-750/? D/TtsServiceFragment: TTS engine for settings screen initialized.
2020-09-08 08:24:01.430 750-750/? D/TtsServiceFragment: Updating engine: Checking voice data: #Intent;action=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA;package=com.google.android.tts;end
2020-09-08 08:24:01.435 558-6628/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA pkg=com.google.android.tts cmp=com.google.android.tts/.settings.CheckVoiceData} from uid 1000
2020-09-08 08:24:01.488 9249-9262/? I/TTS: For default lang de-de is name de-DE-language (de-de-x-nfh-server)
2020-09-08 08:24:01.760 9249-9261/? I/TTS: For default lang de-de is name de-DE-language (de-de-x-nfh-server)
2020-09-08 08:24:01.845 9249-9270/? I/TTS: de-de (1) has status 1, waiting for download
2020-09-08 08:24:01.845 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Skipping already active download: de-de
2020-09-08 08:24:01.845 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Voice download for de-de-x-nfh-lstm-embedded dispatched
2020-09-08 08:24:02.047 9249-9249/? I/TTS: Cache cleared
2020-09-08 08:24:02.186 750-750/? D/TtsServiceFragment: Voice integrity check: Intent { (has extras) }
2020-09-08 08:24:02.193 9249-9262/? I/TTS: For default lang de-de is name de-DE-language (de-de-x-nfh-server)
2020-09-08 08:24:02.221 9249-9270/? I/TTS: de-de (1) has status 1, waiting for download
2020-09-08 08:24:02.222 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Skipping already active download: de-de
2020-09-08 08:24:02.222 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Voice download for de-de-x-nfh-lstm-embedded dispatched
2020-09-08 08:24:02.975 750-750/? D/TtsServiceFragment: Getting sample text: #Intent;action=android.speech.tts.engine.GET_SAMPLE_TEXT;package=com.google.android.tts;S.language=de;S.variant=;S.country=DE;end
2020-09-08 08:24:02.979 558-932/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.speech.tts.engine.GET_SAMPLE_TEXT pkg=com.google.android.tts cmp=com.google.android.tts/.settings.GetSampleText (has extras)} from uid 1000
2020-09-08 08:24:03.699 750-750/? D/TtsServiceFragment: Got sample text: Dies ist ein Beispiel für Sprachsynthese in Deutsch.
2020-09-08 08:24:05.671 750-750/? D/TtsServiceFragment: Speaking sample text
2020-09-08 08:24:06.036 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Synthesis request for locale deu-DEU and name de-DE-language
2020-09-08 08:24:06.080 9249-9270/? I/TTS: de-de (1) has status 1, waiting for download
2020-09-08 08:24:06.080 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Skipping already active download: de-de
2020-09-08 08:24:06.080 9249-9270/? I/TTS: Voice download for de-de-x-nfh-lstm-embedded dispatched
2020-09-08 08:24:06.080 9249-9270/? W/TTS: Local voice not installed, we use the network voice
2020-09-08 08:24:06.083 9249-9270/? I/TTS: TTS dispatch: de-de-x-nfh-server
2020-09-08 08:24:35.592 9249-9249/? I/TTS: Flushing cache
```

as you can see, it tries to download that zvoice package... but it seems not to be able to do so, because no matter how long I wait it will repeat that "Local voice not installed, we use the network voice" expression.
The URL it declares seems to be a forward (curl told me that), but at the end of that zvoice file does appear... which validity I cannot declare outside the watch.
Internet is provided by a WLAN hotspot (yes, internet does work)... proof of that is that the network voice can be used. But as soon as the internet is disconnected... silence.

As a matter of fact, I do have a second watch (same model, same os version), where the tts seems to work perfectly, even after a reset for reconection.

EDiT: I had the chance to at least ask about the behavior of that second watch. As far as the current owner was able to tell me over the phone, after selecting a new language and hitting the example speech for the second time his watch claims to have the needed package and tells him that tts for that voice was set up using the local speech package. Afterwards his watch can talk in Chinese even if he disconnects from the internet.

We do have the same service app version for google speech, but his app contains about 30Mb in data and cache, while mine barely contains 100kB... I tried to peek inside the folders that may contain these kB, but the "adb shell" user is not permitted to do anything than loiter around at the root folder.

So, any idea why that particular watch cannot acquire that zvoice package. Or... can I get that zvoice package in my watch using other means?

Comment: Is installation of applications from other sources (like USB) allowed? Then you could try to install an apk version of the zvoice package manually, something like `adb install zvoice.apk`

Comment: @SCCC, that package it wants to use is not an apk, as far as I can tell... its filename is "de-de-r2.zvoice", with zvoice being the extension. But I will try what happens if ti feed it the apk installer... nope, says file does not end with .apk, and - of course - renaming it did confuse the adb even more